# WARNING playername moved too quickly!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am running a dedicated vanilla 1.6.1 server so that my friend over in America can connect and play along with me. The server is whitelisted, we're both in the list and have OP permissions. Playing creative mode.

We're building TNT cannons, some of which are designed to launch your player. We built one example which can launch a player over 700 blocks high - and my friend has no problem using this.

However, when I step in and launch myself, as the server host, it tells me that I am moving too quickly. My position is reset and I don't get launched in to the air. I have tried setting the `allow-flight` flag in the server properties file to `true`, but it still causes the warning to show.

Any ideas as to why I am affected, but my friend isn't?

Computer specs:

- Intel i5 3570k processor @ 4Ghz
- 8GB DDR3 @ 1500 Mhz
- Sandisk Pulse SSD
- NVIDIA GTX 670

Minecraft runs in windowed mode, but maximised.

My ping to the server is < 1ms (obviously), friend's ping is about 140ms.. Give or take 10ms.

Comment: I'm confused by the existence of close votes on this clearly-expressed problem.

Comment: Hm, you may just have to switch to Bukkit. You don't have to install any plugins, but Bukkit comes with options to disable this.

Comment: @avestar101 Thanks for you reply. I made a copy of the world and installed Bukkit, but to no avail. Would you mind expanding on how Bukkit can prevent this behaviour?

Edit: Forgot to mention that I have gone through the bukkit config files but couldn't find any useful settings.

Comment: @Alexbrock 
1. Open up bukkit.yml, in the same folder as your server jar.
2. Look under the first section settings.
3. Find kick-on-speedhack and set it to false.                            (All of this was taken from a post on Minecraftforums.net)

Comment: @avestar101 It appears that the settings may have been deprecated some time ago. I'm currently experimenting with different plugins to see if I can work around this, but I'm still open to other potential solutions.

Answer (score 1):

My bukkit server still has the kick-on-speedhack parameter in the bukkit.yml file, but that might not be evidence of it being deprecated.

Add:
kick-on-speedhack: false

under settings: anyway to give it a go if you haven't already.

Comment: They're running vanilla, so Bukkit solutions probably won't help much.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm afraid that even with the addition of bukkit, this feature appears to not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on an Agrarian Skies server.

All players within the affected area/chunk were getting stuck in place (I don't like getting reset back to the same spot repeatedly) and the server window was spammed with the moving too fast message.

We did find a suggestion to allow flight was helpful in clearing us from being stuck sooner however it did not resolve the issue.

Because it was within a 'bee' production area we pinpointed that **the bees were causing the issue**.  We eventually resolved this by using an Inoculator (from Extra Bees mod) to remove the GRAVITY affect from certain bee types.  Without the affect there is was no further spam to the server and we didn't get stuck in the environment around the bee production area.  Just watch the bee doesn't revert to having the affect again (this happened a few times to me).

Comment: How does this at all help the OP? He clearly states he was using Vanilla, not a modpack like Agrarian Skies. This answer is solely dedicated towards fixing specific issues that can't at all be the problem

Answer (score 0):

For others who may come here, I was able to fix this on my vanilla server by setting

```
allow-flight=true
```

in the file **server.properties**.